# How to use Simple HTML DOM PHP to get span data-reactid value?

Tags: php, html, class, dom

Neither of these work:

```
$html = file_get_html("https://www.example.com/page/");
print($html->find('[data-reactid=10]', 0)->plaintext);
print($html->find('[data-reactid=11]', 0)->plaintext);
```

where the html looks like this:

```
<div class="stuff" data-reactid="10">
<span data-reactid="11">Value I want</span>
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

FYI. this does work:

```
print($html->find('[data-reactid=5]', 0)->plaintext);`
```

where:

```
<div class"stuff" data-reactid="5">
<!-- react-text: 6 -->
Value I want
<!-- /react-text:  -->
</div>
```

So how do I get the value with the span?
I can get the value with the div.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just get the value of: data-reactid="11"

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$html_str = '
    <div class="stuff" data-reactid="10">
    <span data-reactid="11">Value I want</span>
    </div>
';

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($html_str);

// Get the value
echo $html->find('div[data-reactid=10]', 0)->find('span', 0)->{'data-reactid'};
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks... but I cut and pasted your code and it didn't return anything?

Comment: The same code returned 11 for me. Which version of php do you use?